# After upgrading to 4.6.18, cannot enter credit card details in event registration

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, payment-processor

We just upgraded our site at www.fremantlechamber.com.au to the latest version of Drupal and CiviCRM 4.6.18

Now when we try to register for an event, the credit card details are not appearing and noone can pay for registration.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say which payment processor you are using as this may be related to this issue.

Comment: Im using the eway payment processor. Not sure if that could be the reason

Answer (score 1):

I had a look and can you entire billing block is indeed MIA.

**Two thoughts:**

1) get into the Event Registration Config and try re-adding the Payment Processor - re-save

2) check for errors in your ConfigAndLog/ when you load this form

EDIT - more thoughts:

3) check the Payment Processors their config - and create a (Test) Contribution page where you run a transaction with a fake credit card

4) (in general) check the Manage Extensions screen and look if there are any upgrades for your Payment Processor (of course this only applies to those which are not baked in core)

Comment: I tried what you said and am now getting the following error when trying to access the registration page                                                          Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Invalid value passed to getPayment function
Return to home page.  Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is not appearing now  - as I had to recheck the eway payment processor in the event - but I still cant see the area to enter credit card details

Comment: Please see above for some more troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of creating a dummy payment processor and trying to create a test contribution.  Still not able to view the block to enter credit card details unfortunately.  Could it have something to do with Drupal scripts ?

Comment: Next is indeed to check for custom_php; custom_tpl and/or scripts that may interfere. Can you run a transaction with a dummy payment processor in the backend (so from the Contact Summary -> Contributions tab -> Submit Credit Card Contribution?